# Retrieve location from database and display it in a MapView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-mapview

I have an application where I fetch longitude and latitude from my database and want to display it in a `MapView`. I am able to show the one stored most recently, but I think some array is needed in a `for` loop to add it in an overlay. I don't know how to implement it though.

Here is my buttonClick on which it will fetch lat/long and display it in a `MapView`:

```
buttonShowMarkers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_SHOW_MARKERS);

buttonShowMarkers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("LocationFetch.db", MODE_PRIVATE , null);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user" , null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                int dataID = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
                String dataString = cursor.getString(0);
                Log.d("ID DATA FROM DATABASE---->" , dataString);

                String dataNAME = cursor.getString(1).toString().trim();
                Log.d("NAME DATA FROM DATABASE---->", dataNAME);

                String dataLAT = cursor.getString(2).toString().trim();
                Log.d("LAT DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLAT);
                int latitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude");

                String dataLON = cursor.getString(3).toString().trim();
                Log.d("LON DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLON);
                int longitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude");

                showLatLon(latitude , longitude , dataNAME);
                // ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
                /* List<Overlay> ListOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                 * OverlayItem[] markerItem = {new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataString)};
                 * OverlayItem markerItem = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(latitude *1E6), (int)(longitude *1E6)) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataString);
                 * drawableOne = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_blue);          
                 * helloItemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawableOne);
                 * helloItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(markerItem);
                 * mapView.getOverlays().add(helloItemizedOverlay);
                 * ListOverlays.add(myItemizedOverlay);*/

                //for(int i = dataID ; )
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());  

            /*String[] arrLat = new String[]{LATdata};
              String[] arrLon = new String[]{LONdata};*/

            //showLatLon(dataLAT , dataLON);                    
            cursor.moveToNext();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();
    }           

    private void showLatLon(int latitude , int longitude , String nAMEdata) {
        // GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint( (latitude) , (latitude) );

        List<Overlay> ListOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        //OverlayItem[] markerItem = {new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataString)};
        OverlayItem markerItem = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude,latitude ) , ""+nAMEdata , null);
        drawableOne = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_blue);

        helloItemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawableOne);           
        helloItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(markerItem);

        mapView.getOverlays().add(helloItemizedOverlay);

        ListOverlays.add(myItemizedOverlay);
    }           
});
```

Comment: MapView? Is there a reason you're not using the Android Gmaps API v2?

Comment: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. Developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: I am using gingerbread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this solution -

1. Create a class named **LatLonPoint** - this basically does the conversion from latlon to GeoPoint -

```
public class LatLonPoint extends GeoPoint {
public LatLonPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
    super((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
}
}
```

Create a Itemized Overlay -

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event, MapView mapView) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event, mapView);
}
```

}

Now in the main activity -

```
 try {
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("LocationFetch.db", MODE_PRIVATE , null);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user" , null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            do {
                int dataID = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
                String dataString = cursor.getString(0);
                Log.d("ID DATA FROM DATABASE---->" , dataString);

                String dataNAME = cursor.getString(1).toString().trim();
                Log.d("NAME DATA FROM DATABASE---->", dataNAME);

                String dataLAT = cursor.getString(2).toString().trim();
                Log.d("LAT DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLAT);
                int latitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude");

                String dataLON = cursor.getString(3).toString().trim();
                Log.d("LON DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLON);
                int longitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude");

                    // Add the item here --
                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(new LatLonPoint(latitude, longitude), dataNAME, null));


                //showLatLon(latitude , longitude , dataNAME);
                // ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
                /* List<Overlay> ListOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                 * OverlayItem[] markerItem = {new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataString)};
                 * OverlayItem markerItem = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(latitude *1E6), (int)(longitude *1E6)) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataString);
                 * drawableOne = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_blue);          
                 * helloItemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawableOne);
                 * helloItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(markerItem);
                 * mapView.getOverlays().add(helloItemizedOverlay);
                 * ListOverlays.add(myItemizedOverlay);*/

                //for(int i = dataID ; )
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 

                // Add all itemized overlay here 
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);


            /*String[] arrLat = new String[]{LATdata};
              String[] arrLon = new String[]{LONdata};*/

            //showLatLon(dataLAT , dataLON);                    
            //cursor.moveToNext();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
```

For the above block you have to initialize these two items beffore the **do.. while** -

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
```

and

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
            drawable, this);
```

**EDIT-- Adding iterating Cursor Part -**

```
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
            HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
                    drawable, this);
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                // get the values -- 
                int dataID = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");

                String dataString = cursor.getString(0);
                Log.d("ID DATA FROM DATABASE---->" , dataString);

                String dataNAME = cursor.getString(1).toString().trim();
                Log.d("NAME DATA FROM DATABASE---->", dataNAME);

                String dataLAT = cursor.getString(2).toString().trim();
                Log.d("LAT DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLAT);

                int latitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude");
                String dataLON = cursor.getString(3).toString().trim();
                Log.d("LON DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLON);
                int longitude = cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude");

                // Assuming your logic for retrieving values is correct 
                // Add into the itemized Overlay here 
                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(new LatLonPoint(latitude, longitude), dataNAME, null));

            }
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

Comment: @Ankool Its not working dear, its giving me error cursor OutOfBoundException. Even if I write outside while loop how will I get latitude and longitude.Help me again SOS.

Comment: Somehow i think the second cursor.moveToNext() is not required. Try to comment that one. Check the edit.

Comment: Well I have debugged that exception but now am getting only last value which i entered into database, i.e, recent data. And how to show it in map view for all d lats and longs.

Comment: The basic idea is - in your while loop you are getting the lats and longs , Add each of them in the itemizedOverlays(For every iteration). And when all the iterations are done just add this itemized overlay to mapOverlay. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still its not working Ankool , i copied your code exactly what u have written. Dnt know whats wrong. Am now banging my head, and tried also with for loop.

Comment: iTs not showing any marker on the map.Thats the issue. Now tell me is my overlay alryt? Shall I send you the entire code ?

Comment: OH Finally its working. Thank you so very much now i can see all the markers in blue. Thank you so very much, but still thee is only one problem its taking too much time load for which sometimes it shows ANR. Please help. And once again thank you.... :-)